# VBA DoCmd.TransferText - exporting query to .csv with user defined file path

Tags: vba

Currently my code is this:

```
Dim testSQL As String
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

testSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryExample WHERE exampleID IN (" & strExampleIDList & ")"
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("tmpExport", testSQL)
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", "C:\export.csv"
db.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport"
```

How do I change the "C:\export.csv" part so that the user is able to define the file path and the file name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you want the user to be prompted for input, and then use that input in your TransferText call, try this:

```
Dim UserInput As String
UserInput  = InputBox("Please enter the file path.", "I WANT A VALUE!") 
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", UserInput
```

There are other approaches out there, but this is perhaps the easiest to implement.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this is better than what I had - however, I'm after the windows explorer box that the user would normally use to perform such an action.

Comment: Ah, then you're wanting to use the FileDialog -- look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824272

Answer (score 8):

This example will allow you to use the filedialog Save-As object:

To use this function, you must add a reference to the "Microsoft Office XX.0 Object Library". Add a new module and paste the following function:

```
    Public Sub exportQuery(exportSQL As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Check to see if querydef exists
    For i = 0 To (db.QueryDefs.Count - 1)
        If db.QueryDefs(i).Name = "tmpExport" Then
            db.QueryDefs.Delete ("tmpExport")
            Exit For
    End If
    Next i

    Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("tmpExport", exportSQL)

    'Set intial filename
    fd.InitialFileName = "export_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyy") & ".csv"

    If fd.show = True Then
        If Format(fd.SelectedItems(1)) <> vbNullString Then
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", fd.SelectedItems(1), False
        End If
    End If

    'Cleanup
    db.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport"
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set qd = Nothing
    Set fd = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Now within your code where you want to start the export, use:
        Call exportQuery("SELECT * FROM...")

I recommend defining a string variable for your SQL query.

```
    Public Sub someButton_Click()
    Dim queryStr as String
    'Store Query Here:
    queryStr = "SELECT * FROM..."

    Call exportQuery(queryStr)

    End Sub
```