# Exporting Access to CSV

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I want to export the access query into csv file. For that I am using the following format which was given in the previous discussion in stack overflow.

```
Function ExportQuery()
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "[your query]", "[output file].csv"
End Function
```

I get the output as CSV file but the data is separated in the columns of the sheet. I want the data separated by the semi-colon in the first column itself of all the columns.

Please revert back asap.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. What do you mean 'the data is separated in the columns of the sheet'? And I don't understand your next sentence at all, 'I want the data separated by the semi-colon in the first column itself of all the columns'. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.

If you want to put any delimiter like comma, semicolon,etc..

Double click on the Query or table whichever you want to export. Then click on Export in the File Tab. Give the file name and select text files (Access 2003). Then click on Export All. Export Text Wizard will open. Select radio Button delimited and click on Advanced. Then select   Field Delimiter of what you want. And select Text Qualifier as none. Then select "Save As"
and give the name to the Specification. And complete the whole process as you do in the manual process. After saving it close both the files CSV and access.

The VBA Code will be as given below after saving the specification name:

```
Function ExportQuery()
     DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim,"Specification Name" , "[your query]", "[output file].csv"
End Function
```

So only Add "Specification Name" in the code.

Comment: Note that it only works with table because the third argument is "TableName". If you want to export from query you need to use a DAO.QueryDef. Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700192/vba-docmd-transfertext-exporting-query-to-csv-with-user-defined-file-path

Comment: For me, the third argument is the name of a query, and it works okay.  By the way, if you want to include column headers, you'll need to include True as a fifth argument, even if you think you already selected that option in your specification.  See [DoCmd.TransferText method (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext)

Answer (score 0):

Exporting Access database to csv files can easily be done using the Java code here:

https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/access-to-csv-tool

This code includes complete examples in the test code and does a complete export of the nortwinds data base.

See the class AccessToCsvUtil for the code to convert a single table to a .csv file.

See the class WriteToCsvIntegration test to see code that exports all of the tables in the database.

This utility is based on the ucanaccess jdbc tool and the Apache commons-csv tool.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```