# MS Access: Command button to export a report to a CSV file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was wondering if this was possible.  I have my main form with a bunch of tables on it, and then I have a report.  Standard stuff there.  The report is named `Report1`.  What I was wondering, is there a way I can put a command button on my main form, that when pressed, will export `Report1` onto my desktop (or wherever I specify) in a CSV format?  I would like to do this in VBA if possible.  I'm not sure if I could make a macro format into CSV, but I am pretty open to any suggestions.  Thank you

Comment: You can export the report's data to CSV by using [DoCmd.TransferText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214141(v=office.12).aspx) with the report's Record Source table or named query.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the report's data to CSV by using DoCmd.TransferText with the report's Record Source table or named query.

Take a look at this: [VBA DoCmd.TransferText - exporting query to .csv with user defined file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700192/vba-docmd-transfertext-exporting-query-to-csv-with-user-defined-file-path)

Comment: Thanks that is a good example.  Do you know how I could export the report I have made though? And not a query like in that example?

Answer (score 0):

A report is always based on a query.

You can find your query in the properties within the Design View of your report ("RecordSource").

The best way should be to generate a query (based on your current report) and link that query to the report ("RecordSource") and to the export button (DoCmd.TransferText).
Thereby, if you want to change your report / report data, you only need to change it once.