# Exporting MySQL table to .csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vba

This is my first day with VBA. I am trying to export a .csv file in MS Access using MySQL query in VBA. I have tried using this code:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set db = CurrentDb

sql = "SELECT wo_id FROM WorkOrder"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "rs", "C:\export.csv", True

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

which gives me:

> Run time error '3011':
>
> The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'rs'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and path name correctly

MORE INFO

I have a MySQL table called WorkOrder (I would like to pull data from here).

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700192/vba-docmd-transfertext-exporting-query-to-csv-with-user-defined-file-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only export MS-Access objects (tables or queries) using `DoCmd.TransferText`. If you have a query called `qryOutput` you can export it:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryOutput", "C:\export.csv", True
```

You could create the query on runtime (using `db.CreateQueryDef`), export it and delete it.

---

If you are working with MySQL, maybe it is easier to export the data directly from the command line:

```
c:\> mysql -h YourHost -u YourUser -pYourPassword dbYourDatabase -e"SELECT wo_id FROM WorkOrder" > c:\export.txt
```

This will create a tab-separated text file with the result of your query (including headers).

On a Unix-like command line you could convert this output on-the-fly to a comma separated text file using `sed`:

```
$ mysql [connectionParameters] -e"select..." | sed 's/\t/,/g' > export.csv
```

I don't know if there are any pure-windows command line utilities to do this. I use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for this kind of things. If you want to use it, be sure to install `sed` using Cygwin Setup program.

Hope this helps.